# Sort numbers in order to use them for a sample list or convert a list in an array and back

Tags: lists, arrays, sorting

I've tried multiple times to get help for little parts of my project but I can't make it work, so here I am with a bigger chunk.

My problem: I generate a list of numbers for points where I want my function to be evaluated (adding points near values of interest) and this list is not ordered properly. So I have been trying to sort it before plotting my function otherwise the plot is scrambled

Here it is with minimum cleaning :

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
 
\usepackage{listofitems} % \readlist\WcArray{0.1,1,10}

\usepgflibrary{fpu} % Avoid usual Latex calculation limits 
\newcommand\pgfmathparseFPU[1]{\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathparse{#1}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}%

% evenly spaced point from start to end
\newcommand*{\CreateList}{
\def\mySamplLst{\Wmin}
\xdef\mySamplNb{10}
\pgfmathparseFPU{(\Wmax/\Wmin)^(1/\mySamplNb)}
\xdef\myStep{\pgfmathresult}
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,\mySamplNb} {\pgfmathparseFPU{\Wmin*(\myStep^(\i))}
  \xdef\mySamplLst{\mySamplLst,\pgfmathresult}}
  
% evenly spaced point around a point of interest
\foreach \j in {1,...,\WcArraylen}{
\def\mySamplNb{5}
\def\mySamplCenter{\WcArray[\j]}
\def\mySamplwidth{10}
\pgfmathparseFPU{\mySamplwidth^(1/\mySamplNb)}
\xdef\myStep{\pgfmathresult}
\foreach \i in {-\mySamplNb,...,-1,0,1,2,...,\mySamplNb} {\pgfmathparseFPU{\mySamplCenter*(\myStep^(\i))}
  \xdef\mySamplLst{\mySamplLst,\pgfmathresult}}
}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \def\Wmax{10^(2)}
    \def\Wmin{.01}
        \readlist\WcArray{0.1,1,10}
    \CreateList
    \begin{semilogxaxis}
        \expanded{\noexpand
            \addplot [samples at={\mySamplLst}] %=200,domain=\Wmin:\Wmax,mark=+]
            {   -20*(log10(x))
                +10*(log10((1-(x)^2)^2+4*(0.1^2)*(x)^2)) 
            }[green!80!black,very thick];
        }
    \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

giving :

[image]

How you can help me

- Sort my list :

  - I've received help before, codes working for a list you type but it doesn't work with my generated list.
- Transform my list into an array, and the array back into a list

  - I've found a way to sort an array but I don't know how to switch form my list to an array. And I'll need the way back to for my plot.

  Sort an array :

  ```
   \usepackage[comparestr,comparenum,randompart]{arraysort}

   \begin{document} 
   \newarray{A}
   \readarray{A}{78&4&85&1&28&6&0.1&0.07}
   \sortArray{8}{A}
   \A(1) \A(2) \A(3) \A(4) \A(5) \A(6)
   \end{document}
  ```

But you can see it use `&` as a separator and a list uses `,` so I can't just use : `\readarray{A}{\mySamplLst}`

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example doesn't compile. I get an error

```
 ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgfplots/mysum',
```

But you can sort your list with this code

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \LMTsortlist #1
 {
  \clist_sort:Nn #1 
   {
    \fp_compare:nNnTF {##1}>{##2}
     {\sort_return_swapped:}
     {\sort_return_same: }
   } 
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

and then later

```
\LMTsortlist \mySamplLst
```

Comment: My code did compile on Overleaf for me. But I removed the lines I forgot in my simplifications to post here, does it compile for you too now ? Thank you I'll try your solution

Comment: your new example compiles, but you see it is not trivial to give a working exemple. consider this before throwing stones at other people.